# Textbox with styled scrollbar no longer auto scrolls WPF

Tags: wpf, templates, scrollbar, styling

I have a scrollviewer style & template (and accompanying scrollbars) and they work fine in virtually all cases, but it changes the behavior of the textbox so that when you go past the confines of the textbox the scrolling does not automatically kick in.

Example:

if the box is 50px and you type text that is longer that the 50px, then you'll be able to keep typing, but scrollviewer does not scroll so that you can see the latest text in the view.

I've take the templates for the scrollviewer and bars directly from the MS template and only simplified it down.  It's a lot of code to paste into the question, so if you want to see it let me know.

I was hoping that someone might have come across this problem before and have a simple answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue myself and spent quite a while trying to work it out.

In the default ScrollViewer template, there is

```
<ScrollContentPresenter />
```

Replace this with

```
<ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />
```